# unable to install packages from apm on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, atom-editor

after trying to install linter by typing: **apm install linter-jsonlint**
I get the following error...

```
  Installing linter-jsonlint to /home/user/.atom/packages ✗
  Request for package information failed: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=write EPROTO 140718467635008:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:794:

  (5 attempts) (ECONNRESET)
```

I've set the https_proxy, http_proxy variables and strictSSL=false

Answer (score 0):

Command is correct but may be the path is not found. Delete the file save the newly downloaded file. After you unzip it, use
    apm install

To check configuration use apm config

If nothing works check apm help
If nothing comes, it means that the package is not found.